# WebAPI "debugging" - check open SQL connections?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, garbage-collection

Is there a possibility to have a look at all SQL connections that are still open or were closed by GC?

Or can I globally ask the GC to log when an SQL connection is closed by him? (maybe into the SQL database, through that connection before he closes it?)

I am searching for unclosed connections by looking at the code right now, but is there a way to do it by testing/logging?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to ask the server:

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

For connection management it is easiest to either put each connection into a using block (then it is guaranteed to be safe) or put the connection management into a central place (open in BeginRequest, close in EndRequest).

Comment: OK, I see the connection. But it does not tell me which part of our program opened the connection, so it seems that this part of the question does not help to solve the original problem. :(